# Let $X$ be an independent exponential R.V. with parameter $\lambda$. Bound $P(X > x)$ using Chebyshev, and then calculate it directly.

Tags: probability-theory

If $x > \mu$, then Chebyshev's inequality can be used to bound $P(X > x)$, as shown by the following analysis: [Using Chebyshev's inequality, which gives a bound on $P(\mid X - \mu \mid \geq y)$ to bound $P(X > x)$ or $P(X < x)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3471390/using-chebyshevs-inequality-which-gives-a-bound-on-p-mid-x-mu-mid-geq-y)

Since $X$ is an exponential R.V., say with parameter $\lambda$, then:

$$ \mu = \frac{1}{\lambda}, \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} $$

So to find the probability that $P(X > x)$, assuming $x > \mu$:

\begin{align*}
&\quad P(X \geq y + \mu) \\
&\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{y^2}
\end{align*}

Let $x = y + \mu$, then $y = x - \mu$, and we have:

$$ P(X > x) \leq \frac{1}{\lambda^2 y^2} = \frac{1}{\lambda^2(x - \frac{1}{\lambda})^2}$$

Alternatively, using the cdf of $\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$:

$$ P(X > x) = 1 - P(X < x) = e^{-\lambda x}$$

It remains to show that for $x > \mu = 1/\lambda$:

$$e^{-\lambda x} \leq \frac{1}{\lambda^2 y^2} = \frac{1}{\lambda^2(x - \frac{1}{\lambda})^2}$$.

But this is trivially true because the exponential decays faster than any negative power function.

Suppose $\lambda = 3$, and $x = 2$. Clearly, $x > \frac{1}{3}$. Then the bound obtained via Chebyshev's inequality predicts:

$$ P(X > 2) = \frac{1}{9 \times (2 - \frac{1}{3})^2} = 0.04$$

On the other hand, using the complement of the cdf:

$$ P(X > 2) = e^{-3 \times 2} \approx 0.0025 $$

So, Chebyshev's bound is off by an order of magnitude, which matches our expectation that $P(X > x)$ will decay much faster than the upper bound derived using Chebyshev.

---

This is a practice question, which does not have a solution. Since I am prone to making errors, I am typing the solution I found in order to have it verified. Please let me know if everything is in order.

In particular, one thing that bothers me is that it was stated that $X$ is independent, but I did not find the fact relevant to the problem.

Second, while I say that it is "trivially true" that the exponential decays faster than any other decaying power function, I do not know how to show that this is true rigorously. I suppose one could use Taylor series?

Comment: Why $P(-y \geq X - \mu \;\vee\; X - \mu \geq y)=P(X - \mu \geq y)$?

Comment: @Math-fun Mistake on my part. I have added some stuff which will hopefully fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To prove $e^{-a}\leq\frac{1}{(a-1)^2}$ for $a\geq 0$ :

Observe that the function $(a-1)^2e^{-a}$ has derivative $(3-a)(a-1)e^{-a}$ which is $0$ at $1$ and $3$, it is negative on $(0,1)\cup (3,\infty)$ and positive on $(1,3)$, hence the only two local maximums are at $0$ and $3$, respectively corresponding to value $1$ and $4 e^{-2}<4 \times 2^{-2}=1$ since $e>2$. Now you have proved that $e^{-a}\leq\frac{1}{(a-1)^2}$ with equality if and only if $a=0$.

For the part where you assume that $y>0$, I think you want to assume that $y> \mu$ instead.

Comment: I have heavily updated my work. What do you think now?